# Suppose $a$ is small and $F: a \rightarrow b$ is a surjection. Is $b$ small?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Define a class as small if there is no injection from $V$ into the class. Suppose then that $a$ is small and let $F: a \rightarrow b$ be a surjection. Is $b$ small?

If we assume Choice, the answer is yes, since, if there is a surjection from $a$ to $b$, then there is an injection from $b$ to $a$, and then, if $b$ is not small, $a$ is not either. But what if we *don't* assume Choice (and, moreover, do not assume Replacement)? Can we still prove that $b$ is small?

(Incidentally, I'm assuming we are working within $\mathrm{Z}$, i.e. Zermelo's set theory, which is basically $\mathrm{ZFC}$ minus Replacement and Choice. The class terms are all eliminable as in Levy's *Basic Set Theory*.)

Comment: You would need not just Choice but Global Choice for the argument you describe.  (Ordinary Choice only lets you make choices indexed by a *set*.)

Comment: Note also that you may as well assume $b=V$.  (If $b$ is not small, there is a copy of $V$ inside it, and you can restrict $F$ to the inverse image of that copy.)

Comment: @EricWofsey - Right, I am assuming $a$ is a set too.

Comment: hi Nagase. are you sure you want to assume that $a$ is a set? it seems to me that if $a$ is a set and $F:a\to V$ is a surjection, then we may obtain a corresponding surjection $G:a\to P(a)$ (take $G(x)=F(x)$ if $F(x)\in P(a)$ and $G(x)=\varnothing$ otherwise), contradicting Cantor's theorem

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom - Ah, that's nice. Don't you want to post this as an answer?